# one web application multiple database for each client difficulties with recognizing clients  Request.Url.Host

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one `asp.net(iis7)` web app and multiple database in back-end.

Every client has different url for example:

**client1.test.com

client2.test.com**

Application should read url `(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host)` and determine which database use.

The problem is that from `iis7 HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host` in class not working(Request is not available in this context ).

I don't have idea how to replace this mechanism.
One web app for every client is not a solution.

Comment: At what point in the processing pipeline are you trying to use HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host?

Comment: You give me idea :) ,i see now that problem was in application start after this HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host working , i can avoid using  application start for initialization some system settings, thanks

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: 
From IIs7 (integrated mode) Request.Url.Host is not available 
in application start event.
It works later but if you need any initialization in application start you can read blog entry
http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/11/10/Integrated-mode-Request-is-not-available-in-this-context-in-Application_5F00_Start.aspx